# C# timers.timer is not working properly

Tags: c#, timer, intervals

I'm trying to use a timer in C# to run a method at an interval of five seconds. Though this code doesn't seem to work. I do not get any errrors when running it but the program (I run this in a console) shuts down right after `IP.timer1.Start()`. The timer1_Elapsed method is never getting executed. I know that because I've tried making the program print a string to the console at the first line of the timer1_Elapsed method.

```
class Program
{
    Timer timer1 = new Timer();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program IP = new Program();
        IP.timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);
        IP.timer1.Interval = 5000;
        IP.timer1.Enabled = true;
        IP.timer1.Start();

    }

    static void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
    //Function to get executed each time the counter elapses. 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that the `Start` method of the timer starts the timer on another thread, and immediately returns from the method. This causes your `Main` method to end, and the console to shut down.

Depending on what `Timer` you are using (there are a few similarly named classes in the BCL) you may want to implement the fix differently. I suggest reading the documentation on [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.start.aspx) or [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) depending on which it is you are using.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using system.timers.timer. I would really appreciate if you could give me an example of how to implement that fix. Because I can't go with "console.read()" in the future as I will be running my software as a Windows Service later on.

Comment: @user1308385 When you run as a windows service you will not have this problem because the code won't terminate in the same way that a console application does so put the console.readline in for your testing, take a look at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.80).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Your program will exit the moment the main function terminates.

You need to prevent main from exiting until you are ready, possibly with a Console.ReadLine();

Answer (score 0):

The timer starts on another thread, Use the following to suspend the thread until the user hits a key after the timer start.

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I assume this is not a solution. No application in realtime will not wait using this option. For example, this will not work in case of windows forms, windows services will not work in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the program exits right after IP.timer1.Start() is that it is done executing the Main()-function and there is nothing stopping it from returning.

If you want a simple way to keep your program running you can add Console.ReadKey(); after timer1.Start(); so that your application will wait until that function returns (which is when you press any key). After doing this your callback should be called every five seconds as specified.